# Why specific response codes are being replaced by 500 Internal Server Error in Production environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my .Net Core 2.2 application, I have a WebAPI controller that may return response codes 400 and 409.
In the development environment, I can see those codes along with the error messages. But when I deploy the application to the production environment (a virtual machine in Azure) I see just 500 errors without any details. Can anybody explain how to force IIS to return the initially sent error responds?
I return the error responds with the code like the following:

> return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { Message = errorMessage });

Comment: If you're not explicitly returning 500 then 500 indicates that an exception was thrown. You might want to temporarily turn on `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` to give you more detailed responses, or alternatively turn on logging server-side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to amend my Startup as follows:
>public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
>>{
>>>app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
>>>app.UseHsts();
   . . .
>>>}
But it didn't help. I'm still getting 500th errors.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Think about it: you've enabled the page that shows you things like the exception message and stack trace. Why would that change you getting a 500 status response? It won't. It just gives you a means of discovering why there is an exception.

Comment: But I still do not have any details. The only message in the response is: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. In the IIS logs I, for example, can see 401-error but at the same time I'm getting the 500th in the browser.

Comment: For the request where I expect to receive 400 or 409 response codes, I got the 500th code in the IIS log. The code in the controller action is wrapped with try..catch with the error logging in the catch-block, but no new log entries appear.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have turned on the Failed requests tracing and it gave me a clue. The cause was in the fact that the same MIME type was configured twice, one time globally at the IIS level, and the second time at the website level. Once I removed the problematic MIME-type from the website configuration all started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same problem, I solved in the Error Pages area from IIS configuration. When I tried to click, I received a error with the path of web.config from another project. When I solved this error from web.config, the Error Page open correctly and everything work again.